# Xero-Api PHP Authentication Unsuccessful when refreshing token

Tags: refresh-token, xero-api

I am having issues with refreshing tokens with the xero api. When I first create the token, everything is fine. When I refresh the token, I get authentication unsuccessful.

```
{"Type":null,"Title":"Forbidden","Status":403,"Detail":"AuthenticationUnsuccessful","Instance":"8d6256e5-3376-4960-be52-cf8b22ee241c","Extensions":{}}
```

My code is as follows:

```
    public function refreshToken()
    {    
        $provider = new GenericProvider([
            'clientId'                => $valuestore->get('client_id'),
            'clientSecret'            => $valuestore->get('client_secret'),
            'redirectUri'             => $valuestore->get('callback_url'),
            'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize',
            'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://identity.xero.com/connect/token',
            'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Organisation'
        ]);

        $newAccessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
            'refresh_token' => $this->getRefreshToken()
        ]);

        // Save my token, expiration and refresh token
        $this->setOauth($newAccessToken);
    }

public function setOauth($accessToken)
{
    $oauth2 = [
        'token' => $accessToken->getToken(),
        'expires' => $accessToken->getExpires(),
        'tenant_id' => $this->getTenantId(),
        'refresh_token' => $accessToken->getRefreshToken(),
        'id_token' => $accessToken->getValues()["id_token"]
    ];

    //set session
}
```

Thanks in advance

Regards
Danny